# How to find asymptotic bound for $ T(n) = n + \sum_{i=1}^{\lceil \log_3 n \rceil} T(\lfloor \frac {n}{3^i} \rfloor), n\ge 1 $?

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I am solving the recurrence relation:
$$ T(n) = n + \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor} T(\lfloor \frac {n}{3^i} \rfloor), $$

It looks that T(n) at every level is being divided by 3 and the depth of this tree is: $$ \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor $$ Also, expanding first few terms, I got :

$$ T(1) = 1   1$$

$$  T(2) = 2 + T(1) = 3$$

$$  T(3) = 3 + T(1) = 4$$

I have to find a tight asymptotic bound for this recurrence. I am confused about how to proceed from here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you asking how to use the induction hypothesis to show the induction step?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: Yes. I want to use induction hypothesis to show the induction step.